# How do I store binary data in Typescript

Tags: mysql, swift, typescript

I am currently making an app and as part of the app I have users upload an image from their phone library as a profile picture. I currently store all data in a mySQL database. I made a table with the email as the key and the profilepic as a LargeBLOB datatype with the maximum length. In my swift app I figured out how to convert the image into binary data using the following code:

```
let imageData = image.pngData()
let strBase64 = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

I now need to process this through my backend which is written in typescript and I will use a structure similar to that I use to process other string data. This looks like this.

```
const saveData = async function saveData(email: string, data: string): Promise<null> {
    return new Promise<null>(((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = "INSERT INTO Data SET ?"

        const insertData = {
            email: email,
            data: data
        }

        connection.query(query, insertData, (err: MysqlError | null, result: OkPacket | null) => {
            if (err != null) {
                reject(err.message); return;
            }

            if (result != null) {
                if (result.affectedRows == 1) {
                    resolve(null); return;
                } else {
                    reject('Unknown error 1 saving data to database.'); return
                }
            } else {
                reject('Unknown error 2 saving data to database.'); return
            }
        });
    }));
};
```

The only problem is I do not know what data type to use instead of the string I am using for the previous data variable. Does anyone know how I can process this picture data?

Comment: you can use a BLOB (Binary Large Object) data type instead of a string data type

Comment: You've Base64 encoded the image. You don't have binary data. You have a string. When you come to displaying the image, just remember to use appropriate syntax to tell the browser it has a base64-encoded image.

Comment: Omg thank you so much I was messing with it for so long and didn't realize I can just process it as a string. You are a lifesaver!